# How to intent from activity to specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have a home menu with a bottom navbar menu,
in the navbar menu the last tab, I create a button to intent to other activity,

this button from An Activity with BottomNavbar open another activity

```
  @OnClick(R.id.scanQR)
    public void onScan() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),Action_camera.class));
    }
```

in other activity I just use it to get QRcode and send QRcode.result (String) back to the Last Fragment I used in this case Fragment No 3

if I use intent to parent activity from fragment no 3 it will just show fragment no one

```
@OnClick(R.id.cariqr)
    public void onClickqr() {
        Bundle args= new Bundle();
        args.putString("kodebmnscan",textView.getText().toString().trim());
        frag_asset_admin bundle = new frag_asset_admin();
        bundle.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, bundle).commit();
    }
```

how to back to navbar menu the last tab from activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question properly but as much I understand I can help you understand how to move through fragments and activities:

To move from activity to the activity or fragment to activity you use simple intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

to load fragment in a ViePager u simple use FragmentManager like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ViewPagerID, context).commit();
```

So, to start an activity to get results from, you need to get results of QR code back to the home activity. You will do steps like these:

to start an activity for results:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(context,QRCODE.class),REQUEST_CODE);
```

to send back data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

If you don't want to return data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

to receive data back in 'homeactivity':

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
  } 
}
```

If I did not answer your question please elaborate on your question and I will try to answer.

Comment: Sorry about my English, first time i use intent from myhome to an activity and now i need to show it back to my home,

Comment: so you need to get some data back to home activity?
I will update the answer in that case.